# How to give sudo permission for user to run a script with process ID

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, visudo

I want to give sudo permission which does not ask a password while executing the script. The problem I face is I have to provide the process ID as argument while running the script. I have tried in `visudo` the following entry, but it fails and tells no permission to execute the command:

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/jstack 21580
```

I have tried this also:

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/jstack
```

`jstack` is the script to be executed and `21580` is the process ID of `java` which gets changed randomly when do a service restart.

But it is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is the process id passed to the script the script PID or a different one?

Comment: What do you mean by 'process ID of java'? which process?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by removing the (root) in

user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/jstack

and all works fine now. My mistake only :)

The process ID is nothing but the process id for which the stack trace is to be printed.

more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html

Thank you all!!